# Does the azure service configuration file override web.config files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

On any given server there are several sets of config files. Most obviously the Machine.config which sets up a lot of default values and then the web.config .

Any values specified to the web.config take precedence. Does the service configuration file override any of these settings ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, these are different concepts.  They actually have no relationship whatsoever.  I have a post on what the service configuration and config relationship is [here](http://dunnry.com/blog/WhyDoesWindowsAzureUseACscfgFile.aspx).  You will have to substitute 'RoleEnvironment' for 'RoleManager' as things have changed since I last posted this, but it is the kernel of truth here still.